# IBDesignable inside UITableViewCell not rendered properly

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, ibdesignable

I have a grid of custom "text below image" UIButtons inside a static UITableViewCell.

To make 8 UIButtons form 4x2 grid, I put them into 2 horizontal UIStackViews and wrapped them with a vertical UIStackView.
You can see details in the screenshots below.

It runs perfect on simulator and real devices, but not rendered properly in Storyboard. I'd like to know if these are something missing in my code or some settings I should check/uncheck in Storyboard.

Runtime behavior(works well)

[image]

In Storyboard(chaos)

[image]

Outline

[image]

Custom Button:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class YPTextBelowImageButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var heightRatio: CGFloat = 0.8 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = frame
        self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentRect.size.width, height: contentRect.size.height * heightRatio)
    }

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: contentRect.size.height * heightRatio, width: contentRect.size.width, height: contentRect.size.height * (1 - heightRatio))
    }

}
```

Preview:

[image]

func prepareForInterfaceBuilder not working

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: Can't say what is issue but try to implement `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`

Comment: Have you checked Storyboard Preview?

Comment: @jaypatel text label is missing in preview

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya How can I trigger func imageRect and titleRect in func prepareForInterfaceBuilder?

Comment: Maybe try self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()